# Regex to match company names from copyright statements under several conditions (continuation)

Tags: python, regex

I've posted this question today [Regex to match company names from copyright statements under several conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55261787/regex-to-match-company-names-from-copyright-statements-under-several-conditions) to get the company names out of copyright statements, and I've got this regex which works really well for those statements:

```
(?i)(?:©(?:\s*Copyright)?|Copyright(?:\s*©)?)\s*\d+(?:\s*-\s*\d+)?\s*(.*?(?=\W*All\s+rights\s+reserved)|[^.]*(?=\.)|.*)
```

However, now I've just come across an exception: The company name is stated before the year:

> Copyright © Zinrelo, 2019. All rights reserved.

My first idea, not knowing much of regex was trying to build an alternative regex pattern case the first one didn't work, and I came up with this:

```
(?:©(?:\s*Copyright)?|Copyright(?:\s*©)?)\s*(.*?(\d+(?:\s*-\s*\d+)?)|.*)
```

Although it doesn't seem to work so well, I get two matches : 'Zinrelo, 2019', and '2019'. Is there a way I can change the first regex pattern to accomodate for this exception (year is after company name)? If not, what am I doing wrong in the regex pattern I came up with?

Comment: There's only one match, what you report is the content of the two capturing groups defined in your regex. You can use `(?:non-capturing groups)` as in the rest of the regex, or use the relevant python methods to extract the desired information only

Comment: yes, maybe `"(?:©(?:\s*Copyright)?|Copyright(?:\s*©)?)\s*(.*?)(?:\d+(?:\s*-\s*\d+)?)"` -- that means, that you're only interested in the non-greedy capturing group (.*?). This is the text after © and before the digits. All information you're not interested in are in non-capturing groups which are ignored by .findall()

Answer (score 0):

You may use this Pattern to capture and replace unwanted text with nothing, you'll end up with the desired company names that may need anther regex to trim the edges from unwanted characters.

`^.*?©|Copyright|(?:19|20)\d\d|All rights reserved.*$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JvwC4i/1)

```
^               # Start of string/line
.               # Any character except line break
*?              # (zero or more)(lazy)
©               # "©"
|               # OR
Copyright           # "Copyright"
|               # OR
(?:             # Non Capturing Group
  19            # "19"
  |             # OR
  20            # "20"
)               # End of Non Capturing Group
\d              # <digit 0-9>
\d              # <digit 0-9>
|               # OR
All rights reserved     # "All rights reserved"
.               # Any character except line break
*               # (zero or more)(greedy)
$               # End of string/line
```