# Regex to match company names from copyright statements under several conditions (continuation 2)

Tags: python, regex

I posted this question to get a regex pattern to match company names from copyright statements

[Regex to match company names from copyright statements under several conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55261787/regex-to-match-company-names-from-copyright-statements-under-several-conditions/55261973?noredirect=1#comment97256319_55261973)

From which I got this pattern, which works for all the examples I gave in the question:

```
(?i)(?:©(?:\s*Copyright)?|Copyright(?:\s*©)?)\s*\d+(?:\s*-\s*\d+)?\s*(.*?(?=\W*All\s+rights\s+reserved)|[^.]*(?=\.)|.*)
```

I thought it would match everything after the year and before the following dot, although when I try it with:

> Copyright © 2016 Metasystems. ERP Software Provider. All Rights
>   Reserved.

It matches: "Metasystems. ERP Software Provider"

How can I change it to match "Metasystems" in this case and still work correctly for all the examples in the previous question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, after the first company name, you don't want to allow a dot with anything after it, you can use this:

```
(?:©(?:\s*Copyright)?|Copyright(?:\s*©)?)\s*\d+(?:\s*-\s*\d+)?\s*([^\.\n]*?(?=\W*All\s+rights\s+reserved)|[^.\n]*(?=\.)|.*)
```

I've replaced `.*?` with `[^\.\n]*?` so it will accept anything except a dot and a new-line.

See it in actione here:
https://regex101.com/r/Z707J0/1