# Regex to match company names from copyright statements under yet more conditions

Tags: python, regex

I've been for some time trying to find a robust regex to extract company names from copyright statements (and without knowing much of regex).

In this question: [Regex to match company names from copyright statements under several conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55261787/regex-to-match-company-names-from-copyright-statements-under-several-conditions)

I got the regex:

```
(?i)(?:©(?:\s*Copyright)?|Copyright(?:\s*©)?)\s*\d+(?:\s*-\s*\d+)?\s*(.*?(?=\W*All\s+rights\s+reserved)|[^.]*(?=\.)|.*)
```

But as I'm trying with more examples, I'm finding that it's not enough. I want to change it so that it also matches the following conditions, while still working for all the previous cases:

1. Take into account that before "©" or "copyright" (whichever comes last) might come anything else and ignore it.

Examples:

> ```
> 602-226-2389 ©2019 Endurance International Group.
> Copyright 1999 — 2019 © Iflexion. All rights reserved.
> ```

2. Take into account that after the "©" or "copyright" there might not be the year, but the company name already.

Example:

> ```
> ISO 9001:2008, ISO/ IEC 27001:2005 © Mobikasa 2019
> ```

3. Take into account that the year might come before the word "copyright" or "©" (I think that condition 1 also satisfies this)

Examples:

> ```
> © 2019 Copyright arcadia.io.
> 2018 © Power Tools LLC
> ```

4. If there's a | match until there and ignore the rest afterwards:

Example:

> `Copyright 2019 ComputerEase Construction Software | 1-800-544-2530`

Comment: Then, considering the new Rule 4, what is an expected output for `All Comments © Copyright 2017 Kroger | The Kroger Co. All Rights Reserved`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It should be "Kroger"

Comment: There was a rule to stop before a dot, but how about `© 2019 Copyright arcadia.io.`?

Comment: Yap, it's tricky. But in that case we can just keep arcadia

Comment: Check  https://regex101.com/r/n1TBiu/1 then.

Comment: Exactly this. Once again, many thanks! I definitely should get to learn more of regex :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
(?i)(?:©(?:\s*(?:\d{4}(?:\s*[-—–]\s*\d{4})?)?\s*Copyright)?|Copyright(?:\s*(?:\d{4}(?:\s*[-—–]\s*\d{4})?)?\s*©)?)(?:\s*\d{4}(?:\s*[-—–]\s*\d{4})?)?\s*(.*?(?=\s*[.|]|\W*All\s+rights\s+reserved)|.*\b)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/n1TBiu/3)

Python code:

```
import re
s = "Copyright © 2019 Apple Inc. All rights reserved.\r\n© 2019 Quid, Inc. All Rights Reserved.\r\n© 2009 Database Designs \r\n© 2019 Rediker Software, All Rights Reserved\r\n©2019 EVOSUS, INC. ALL RIGHTS RESERVED\r\n© 2019 Walmart. All Rights Reserved.\r\n© Copyright 2003-2019 Exxon Mobil Corporation. All Rights Reserved.\r\nCopyright © 1978-2019 Berkshire Hathaway Inc.\r\n© 2019 McKesson Corporation\r\n© 2019 UnitedHealth Group. All rights reserved.\r\n© Copyright 1999 - 2019 CVS Health\r\nCopyright 2019 General Motors. All Rights Reserved.\r\n© 2019 Ford Motor Company\r\n©2019 AT&T Intellectual Property. All rights reserved.\r\n© 2019 GENERAL ELECTRIC\r\nCopyright ©2019 AmerisourceBergen Corporation. All Rights Reserved.\r\n© 2019 Verizon\r\n© 2019 Fannie Mae\r\nCopyright © 2018 Jonas Construction Software Inc. All rights reserved.\r\nAll Comments © Copyright 2017 Kroger | The Kroger Co. All Rights Reserved\r\n© 2019 Express Scripts Holding Company. All Rights Reserved. 1 Express Way, St. Louis, MO 63121\r\n© 2019 JPMorgan Chase & Co.\r\nCopyright © 1995 - 2018 Boeing. All Rights Reserved.\r\n© 2019 Bank of America Corporation. All rights reserved.\r\n© 1999 - 2019 Wells Fargo. All rights reserved. NMLSR ID 399801\r\n©2019 Cardinal Health. All rights reserved.\r\n© 2019 Quid, Inc All Rights Reserved.\r\n602-226-2389 ©2019 Endurance International Group.\r\nCopyright 1999 — 2019 © Iflexion. All rights reserved.\r\nISO 9001:2008, ISO/ IEC 27001:2005 © Mobikasa 2019\r\n© 2019 Copyright arcadia.io.\r\n2018 © Power Tools LLC\r\nCopyright 2019 ComputerEase Construction Software | 1-800-544-2530\r\n© 2019 3M. 3M Health Information Systems Privacy Policy"
rx = r'''(?xi)
(?:©                                        # Start of a group: © symbol
(?:\s*                                      #  Start of optional group: 0+ whitespaces
  (?:\d{4}                                  #   Start of optional group: 4 digits
    (?:\s*[-—–]\s*\d{4})?                   #     0+ spaces, dashes, spaces, 4 digits
  )?                                        #   End of group
  \s*Copyright                              #  Spaces and Copyright
)?                                          #  End of group 
|                                           #  OR 
Copyright                                   
 (?:\s*                                     #  Start of optional group: 0+ whitespaces
   (?:\d{4}                                 #   Start of optional group: 4 digits
     (?:\s*[-—–]\s*\d{4})?                  #     0+ spaces, dashes, spaces, 4 digits
   )?\s*©                                   #   End of group, 0+ spaces, ©
 )?                                         #  End of group
)                                           # End of group
(?:\s*\d{4}(?:\s*[-—–]\s*\d{4})?)?          # Optional group, 9999 optionally followed with dash enclosed with whitespaces and then 9999
\s*                                         # 0+ whitespaces
(                                           # Start of a capturing group:
   .*?                                      # any 0+ chars other than linebreak chars, as few as possible, up to...
    (?=\s*[.|]|                             # 0+ spaces and then | or ., or
        \W*All\s+rights\s+reserved)         # All rights reserved with any 0+ non-word chars before it
  |                                         # or
   .*\b                                     # any 0+ chars other than linebreak chars, as many as possible
)'''

for m in re.findall(rx, s):
    print(m)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/NMbAFt). Output:

```
Apple Inc
Quid, Inc
Database Designs
Rediker Software
EVOSUS, INC
Walmart
Exxon Mobil Corporation
Berkshire Hathaway Inc
McKesson Corporation
UnitedHealth Group
CVS Health
General Motors
Ford Motor Company
AT&T Intellectual Property
GENERAL ELECTRIC
AmerisourceBergen Corporation
Verizon
Fannie Mae
Jonas Construction Software Inc
Kroger
Express Scripts Holding Company
JPMorgan Chase & Co
Boeing
Bank of America Corporation
Wells Fargo
Cardinal Health
Quid, Inc
Endurance International Group
Iflexion
Mobikasa 2019
arcadia
Power Tools LLC
ComputerEase Construction Software
3M
```

Comment: Last one: what if the company has a number in the name? For instance "© 2019 3M. 3M Health Information Systems Privacy Policy"

Comment: @FilipeAleixo What is the expected result? `3M`?

Comment: "3M". I tried adding the {4} to \d as you said in the first answer, but didn't manage to get it working

Answer (score 0):

I believe [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/YjuMkK/5) gets you what you need. Here's the explanation:

```
(?i)                                # make the regex case insensitive
(?:Copyright\s*©?|©\s*(Copyright)?) # Look for Copyright and/or © to get us started
([\d\s—-]+)?                        # There might be some digits, spaces, and dashes, but not necessarily
(©|Copyright)?\s*                   # Copyright or © could be separated by dates, so look for them again
(.+?)                               # This is the sugar we're looking for
(?=All rights reserved|\||$)        # If you find "All rights reserved" a | or end of string, stop capturing the text
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its old question but want to post better solution.
I trained spacy model which trained on 5k+ copyright text sample.
Here is model and work [Repo Link](https://github.com/aakashkag/Company-Name-Extraction)